# WPF Window reserves space for scrollbar in client area when maximized

Tags: wpf, window, scrollbar, maximize

If I create an empty WPF application from the Visual Studio template and set the window sizes to the resolution of my device, when I maximize the window I see a black strip on the right where it appears a scrollbar would be rendered (but is not and should not be).  Also see the same on the bottom. Note the title bar is the correct maximized width so I assume this is all client area rendering issues.

I removed the default Grid control that comes with the template, so the XAML here is bare bones. In this case I am targeting a display with resolution 1366x768.  Maximize this window in a display set to 1366x768 to see the issue (or change the vals to your display resolution)

Here is the MainWindow.xaml code.  The MainWindow.xaml.cs is untouched default template code.

```
<Window x:Class="TestMaximize.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        Width="1366"
        Height="768"
        MaxWidth="1366"
        MaxHeight="768" >
</Window>
```

What is causing those phantom scrollbar areas and how do I prevent this?

Thanks for any thoughts about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are setting `MaxWidth` to be too small when it's maximized.

If the window is **maximized**, the size of `Window` will be 1382 x 744 (in order to "go to fullscreen". That's basically (1366 + 2*ClientWIndowEdges) x (768 - some amount stripped away from titlebar and bottom).

You are forcing window  to be 1366x768 when it's maximized, thus the actual `Border` inside `Window` will get less space, 1350x760 or something..

You can remove the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` constraint when your window is maximized:

```
<Window x:Class="myNamespace.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="1366" />
                <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="768"></Setter>

            </Style.Setters>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="WindowState" Value="Maximized">
                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="9999" />
                    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="9999"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>

    <Grid Background="LightBlue"></Grid>
</Window>
```

However, I suspect that is not what you want. You actually **want** to have constraints, when your `Window` is maximized. For this, I suggest to use code-behind:

```
private readonly int _maxHeight = 760;
private readonly int _maxWidth = 1366;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DependencyPropertyDescriptor dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty
          (WindowStateProperty, typeof (MainWindow));

    dpd.AddValueChanged(this, (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
        {
            var interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            var barInfo = PInvokeWrapper.GetTitleBarInfoEx(interopHelper.Handle);

            var borderWidth = barInfo.rcTitleBar.Left;

            MaxWidth = _maxWidth + borderWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            MaxWidth = _maxWidth;
            MaxHeight = _maxHeight;
        }
    });

    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
 }
```

The idea is simple, if window is maximized, we recalculate the `MaxWidth` property, including the frame width. I chopped that together with few minutes, it needs debugging through multiple machines to make sure it works everywhere, but it looks 'okayish' to me.

For `GetTitleBarInfoEx`, you might want to check this thread: [How do I compute the non-client window size in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032032/how-do-i-compute-the-non-client-window-size-in-wpf)