# Windows form X button location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am writing a simulation application that shows mouse movements on screen. I can simply locate controls in the form. But now I need to know the location of "X" button (left top corner) on a form. 
How do I get that position?

Comment: For Vista and above, this [is present in the `WM_GET­TITLE­BAR­INFO­EX` message](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/05/05/10522553.aspx).  For XP and below, it [is more complicated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/06/30/10538242.aspx).

Comment: Just to make myself clear, by "X" button I mean the button on the form that closes.

Comment: And also, I want it in C# please.

Comment: That's nice.  Have you tried writing it yourself instead of using StackOverflow as a code generator?  It should be simple work to translate the samples I pointed you towards. (And [searching for a minute or two](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6032327/138200) gets you 90% of the way there)

Answer (score -2):

Try this, if I'm understanding correctly.

```
 int xPos = XButton.Location.X;
 int yPos = XButton.Location.Y;
```

Comment: Pretty sure the OP means the close button, not a button named "XButton" on the form, although its on the right side not the left side. The right side has the icon and context menu.

Comment: @RonBeyer, I agree, but the close button [is on the left in an RTL layout](http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/sshot651.png).  I think the OP is from Australia, though, so I would guess he meant right.

Comment: @Mitch good point, I don't use RTL layouts very much so I overlooked that.

Answer (score -2):

You Can Try it

```
private void show_msg(object source, EventArgs e)
{

    Button b = (Button)source;
    int X = b.Location.X;
    int Y = b.Location.Y;
    MessageBox.Show(X.ToString() + " , " + Y.ToString());

}
```