# C# WPF Keep Window Bottom Right

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Form with `SizeToContent="Height"` and only a `Listbox` in it. During runtime severall items will be added to the `ObservableCollection` the `Listbox` is bound to and the `Listbox` will expand. 
This works just fine but the problem is that I want to keep the Form in the bottom right corner always.

I added the CollectionChanged Event:

```
 ((INotifyCollectionChanged)History.ItemsSource).CollectionChanged +=new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(HistoryCollectionChanged);
```

Snd implemented it the following way:

```
 private void ClipsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
            var desktopWorkingArea = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
            this.Left = desktopWorkingArea.Right - this.ActualWidth;
            this.Top = desktopWorkingArea.Bottom - this.ActualHeight;
        }
```

But although the event gets triggered every time, the positioning is always off.

Comment: Try  applying that to the window's `SizeChanged` event instead.

Comment: You may also have to [adjust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032032/how-do-i-compute-the-non-client-window-size-in-wpf) for the window's "chrome"

Comment: The window has windowstyle=None so that should not matter

Comment: I forgot to mention that the window is hidden during the adding of the element.

Comment: You may need to queue up the move logic for the next time the window is shown.  WPF *may* not update layout information and handle resizing events until the content is shown.

Comment: @BradleyUffner thanks I will try this out